# Не удаляется элемент из Set-a

Tags: android, kotlin, коллекции

Имеется вот такой код. Вся задача в том, чтоб из сета извлечь элемент, а потом удалить его. Это работает в большинстве случаев. Но иногда элемент перестает удаляться. Проверял хэши, они совпадают. Но при удалении возвращает false и элемент остается в сете. Если есть какие-либо идеи, буду очень рад.

```
private val pinCards: MutableSet<Card> = mutableSetOf()

fun addCard(card: Card) {
    if (needShow(card)) {
        wrongPinCards.add(card)
    }
}

fun peekCard(): Card {
    val pickedCard = pinCards.first()
    pinCards.remove(pickedCard)

    return pickedCard
}
```

Comment: возможно проблема в том что размер сета меняется а вы это не учитываете, или это учитывается как-то?

Comment: У него есть одна точка входа. Я сперва добавляю в него n-ое количество элементов. Потом только извлекаю. В большинстве случаев оно работает корректно, но иногда нет удаляется вообще никак.

Comment: `Card` это `data class`? Если нет, то `hashCode` и `equals` переопределяли?

Comment: Это не дата класс, но с хэшами все хорошо. Они переопределены. Я их сверял они идентичны

Comment: @СергейБувака, равенство хэшей не гарантирует равенства объектов, это лишь одно из необходимых условий. Равны ли объекты при вызове переопределённых equals и переопределены ли они?

Comment: Объекты равны. Между этими операциями вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: Скорей всего у вас неправильно переопределены `hashCode` и `equals`, посмотрите на контракты этих методов и контракт между ними и поищите у себя нарушение этих контрактов